# startswith from python to octave

Tags: python, python-2.7, octave

I have a python code and want to write a same one by Octave, but there some commands that I never found them in octave. One part of the code that I did not understand it, is this function:

```
def CVangles(theta, geo, key):

"""
Parameters
    ----------
    theta : float
        The crank angle, between 0 and 2*pi
    geo : struct
        The structure with the geometry obtained from get_geo()
    key : string
        The name of the involute to be considered

   """

     CV = struct()
     CV.Outer = struct()
     CV.Inner = struct()
     if key.startswith('c1.'):
         alpha = int(key.split('.')[1])
         CV.Outer.involute = INVOLUTE_FI
         CV.Outer.phi_0 = geo.phi_fi0       
     return CV
```

how can I express in Octave in startswith and split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strncmp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Comparing-Strings.html#XREFstrncmp) to compare the first 3 characters of `key` with `'c1.'`

```
if strncmp(key, 'c1.', 3)
```

Also, you can use [`strsplit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Manipulating-Strings.html#XREFstrsplit) in place of `split` to split the string into pieces at the `'.'` characters.

```
alpha = strsplit(key, '.'){2};
```

Comment: Thank you Suever I have endless questions :), your help has pleased me and it was useful....can i now ask the next question :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158385/converting-translate-from-python-to-octave-or-matlab

Comment: it is done ...could you please look at my next question in the lenk above ?