# converting/ translate from Python to Octave or Matlab

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, numpy, octave

I have a Python-Code and want to rewrite it in Octave, but I meet so many problems during the converting. I found a solution for some of them and some of them still need your help. Now i would start with this part of the code :

```
INVOLUTE_FI = 0
INVOLUTE_FO = 1
INVOLUTE_OI = 2
INVOLUTE_OO = 3
 def coords_inv(phi, geo,  theta, inv):
        """
        Coordinates of the involutes

        Parameters
        ----------
        phi : float
            The involute angle
        geo : struct
            The structure with the geometry obtained from get_geo()
        theta : float
            The crank angle, between 0 and 2*pi
        inv : int
            The key for the involute to be considered
        """

        rb = geo.rb
        ro = rb*(pi - geo.phi_fi0 + geo.phi_oo0)
        Theta = geo.phi_fie - theta - pi/2.0

        if inv == INVOLUTE_FI:
            x = rb*cos(phi)+rb*(phi-geo.phi_fi0)*sin(phi)
            y = rb*sin(phi)-rb*(phi-geo.phi_fi0)*cos(phi)
        elif inv == INVOLUTE_FO:
            x = rb*cos(phi)+rb*(phi-geo.phi_fo0)*sin(phi)
            y = rb*sin(phi)-rb*(phi-geo.phi_fo0)*cos(phi)
        elif inv == INVOLUTE_OI:
            x = -rb*cos(phi)-rb*(phi-geo.phi_oi0)*sin(phi)+ro*cos(Theta)
            y = -rb*sin(phi)+rb*(phi-geo.phi_oi0)*cos(phi)+ro*sin(Theta)
        elif inv == INVOLUTE_OO:
            x = -rb*cos(phi)-rb*(phi-geo.phi_oo0)*sin(phi)+ro*cos(Theta)
            y = -rb*sin(phi)+rb*(phi-geo.phi_oo0)*cos(phi)+ro*sin(Theta)
        else:
            raise ValueError('flag not valid')

        return x,y
    def CVcoords(CVkey, geo, theta, N = 1000):
        """ 
        Return a tuple of numpy arrays for x,y coordinates for the lines which 
        determine the boundary of the control volume
    Parameters
        ----------
        CVkey : string
            The key for the control volume for which the polygon is desired
        geo : struct
            The structure with the geometry obtained from get_geo()
        theta : float
            The crank angle, between 0 and 2*pi
        N : int
            How many elements to include in each entry in the polygon

        Returns
        -------
        x : numpy array
            X-coordinates of the outline of the control volume
        y : numpy array 
            Y-coordinates of the outline of the control volume
        """

        Nc1 = Nc(theta, geo, 1)
        Nc2 = Nc(theta, geo, 2)

        if CVkey == 'sa':

            r = (2*pi*geo.rb-geo.t)/2.0

            xee,yee = coords_inv(geo.phi_fie,geo,0.0,'fi')
            xse,yse = coords_inv(geo.phi_foe-2*pi,geo,0.0,'fo')
            xoie,yoie = coords_inv(geo.phi_oie,geo,theta,'oi')
            xooe,yooe = coords_inv(geo.phi_ooe,geo,theta,'oo')
            x0,y0 = (xee+xse)/2,(yee+yse)/2 

            beta = atan2(yee-y0,xee-x0)
            t = np.linspace(beta,beta+pi,1000)
            x,y = x0+r*np.cos(t),y0+r*np.sin(t)
              return np.r_[x,xoie,xooe,x[0]],np.r_[y,yoie,yooe,y[0]]
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html I just don´t understand the last Output, and I am still confuse what´s mean _r here, and how can I write it by Octave?....I read what is written in the link, but it still not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
return np.r_[x,xoie,xooe,x[0]], np.r_[y,yoie,yooe,y[0]]
```

The function returns 2 values, both arrays created by `np.r_`.

`np.r_[....]` has indexing syntax, and ends up being translated into a function call to the `np.r_` object.  The result is just the concatenation of the arguments:

```
In [355]: np.r_[1, 3, 6:8, np.array([3,2,1])]
Out[355]: array([1, 3, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1])
```

With the `[]` notation it can accept `slice` like objects (`6:8`) though I don't see any of those here.  I'd have to study the rest of the code to identify whether the other arguments are scalars (single values) or arrays.

My Octave is rusty (though I could experiment with the conversion).

```
t = np.lispace... # I think that exists in Octave, a 1000 values
x = x0+r*np.cos(t)  # a derived array of 1000 values
```

`xoie` one of the values returned by `coords_inv`; may be scalar or array.  `x[0]` the first value of `x`.  So the `r_` probably produces a 1d array made up of `x`, and the subsequent values.

Comment: thank you hpaulj ...I just answer you above but always my answer deleted by @Bhargav Rao :) . now back to the Code ,I think we don´t need np in Octave, but how should this Output be? i wrote it like this x = [x,xoie,xooe,x(1)]; but it is not right? other question in Octave or matlab should i start with the value 0 or 1 ?

Comment: np. is omited any equivalent function.  indexing starts with 1.

Comment: ok thank you so  much, but until now i did not get an exact answer for my main question ...could you please suggest to me the output how should its look like .... is it right so :x = [x,xoie,xooe,x(1)];